# JPA ZonedDateTime value read near daylight savings time change

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

the following indicates a problem with Hibernate and ZonedDateTimes near daylight saving time. when you read times that are near the EDT end , you should not get the same time that you saved in the database. It then states you must change your configuration to set hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC to handle this issue.

Note I'm using an oracle 18 database and the zonedDateTime is stored as a Timestamp type in oracle.

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11621

The problem is also mentionned in this article .
https://thorben-janssen.com/map-date-time-api-jpa-2-2/

I am in Montreal canada. We had EDT (Easter Daylight Time)  from sunday march 8 at 2 am until sunday november 1st 2020 at 2am. It then switches to Easterm standard time (EST).

I am trying to reproduce the problem but can't. Perhaps someone can tell me how to .

Here is what I did

My Entity entity has a field createDate which is a ZonedDateTime

```
    ZonedDateTime zDateTime= ZonedDateTime.of(2020, 11,01,1,0,0,0, ZoneId.systemDefault());
    MyEntity entity = new MyEntity ();
    
    entity .setCreateDate(zDateTime);
    MyEntity savedData = entityRepository.saveAndFlush(testThierry);
```

My timezone is America/New_York

I'm expecting savedData.getCreateDate() to be different dans zDateTime but its not.

I'm probably missing something.

Thank you.